# Belongs_to and has_and_belongs_to_many to the same table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

`Users` create `Programs`. These can be followed/liked by other `Users`. However, the `Program` will ALWAYS have one creator.

So I need a `ProgramsUsers` table to map the like/follow. Would the "creator" also go as a type of relationship in that table, or could a `Program` also `belongs_to` a single specific `User`?

So in essence:

Program.rb

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users    #Likes/Follows
  belongs_to :user                  #Creator
```

Is this acceptable or is this poor modeling?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you can do something like this

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users    #Likes/Follows
  belongs_to :creator, ::class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'creator_id'
```

This way, you can have a `creator_id` field on your `programs` table, and access it using `@program.creator`. Oh, and btw, it is not poor modeling.

Comment: Ugh, I feel like I have seen that before, should've remembered. That's exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: saved me a lot of time, thanks a ton! and +1 for mentioning thats `it is not poor modeling`

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :followings
  has_many :followers, :class_name => 'User', :through => :followings
  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'creator_id'
```